# How do I prevent TMail from dropping the last letters of Hebrew emails?

Tags: ruby, encoding, hebrew, iconv

I am trying to process some incoming emails that contain Hebrew characters encoded in Windows-1255.

Some example content:

```
From: =?windows-1255...
Subject: =?windows-1255...
...

--Boundary_(ID_/GX/qGlPt4gpL8Dqc2zQQg)
Content-type: text/plain;   charset="windows-1255"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable
...
```

The subject is supposed to be "שאלה - ליאור צדוק", but is instead "שאלה - 
ליאור צדו". That is, the last character is dropped. The same is true of the `From` name.

I found [this issue](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1124) on the Iconv list, which describes the same issue. The final word is as follows:

```
In the original code snippet, there's a call to 
    iconv(the_iconv, NULL, NULL, &utf8, &bytes_written);
missing at the end.
```

This jives with the Ruby Iconv documentation (which I've [copied to this Gist](https://gist.github.com/741260)), which emphasizes the importance of adding `nil` to the end of the input.

Nowhere in my code do I use the `Array` or block versions of Iconv; I always use the `Iconv.iconv` helper method, which adds the `nil` for you. I've checked the TMail source and it uses the same `Iconv.iconv` helper.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, that was actually easier than I thought. I had tried adding `nil` to the ends of my `Iconv.iconv` calls to no avail. What I hadn't tried was calling `join` on the result. Thus, the final correct result is

```
Iconv.iconv(to, from, text_to_transcode, nil).join
```